# redirect scaffold ID in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just sent out a campaign with the wrong model ID it's currently /investments/50. Is there a way to redirect to /investments/51?

Is there a way to do this in the console?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want _investments/50_ to still be available to some or all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick (temporary) fix is to redirect in the routes...

```
# Note: This should go at the very top of your routes file
get '/investments/50', to: redirect('/investments/51')
```

This depends on whether or not you need investments/50 to be available (Note: your question doesn't provide much information)

Answer (score 0):

> sent out a campaign with the wrong model ID

You can send out campaign with correct model id from where you have initiated this link for example it's hit on `investments#show` and you are using it's prefix as path

```
investment_path(id: 51)
```

Alternatively you can redirect it from `show` action

```
def show
  #...
  if params[:id].eql?(50)
    redirect_to investment_path(id: 51)
  end
end
```